# Is there a synchronized AND sorted map object (LinkedHashTable)?

Tags: java, dictionary, synchronized, java-6, linkedhashmap

I am creating a `servlet.Filter` implementation wherein I lookup a user ID in a database based on the IP address before sending the request along to the servlet.

I want my filter to stash incoming requests into a map-like object if there is already a request from the same IP address which is being looked up on the database. Then when I get a response from the database, I will apply it to all requests for that IP address and send them on their way to the servlet.

The map-like object would need to be synchronized but also maintain the insertion order so that once I find the user ID all stashed requests "will be handled in the order in which they were received".

Going through the API there is a `LinkedHashMap` which would maintain the order fine but is not synchronized, the `HashTable` is synchronized but doesn't give any indication that it would maintain the right order.

Is there some kind of `LinkedHashTable` object I can use for this?

I am using Java 6.

Comment: That you want it to be ordered seems to imply you want to iterate it?  Bear in mind that simply synchronizing a Map *does not* make it safe to iterate in a concurrent environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29) to wrap any `Map` implementation in a thread-safe container:

```
Map<K, V> synchronizedLinkedHashMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<K, V>());
```

You could also use a [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html) if you want to order your elements with a `Comparator`.

Comment: This, SkipList, simply Synchronizing a Map does not make it magically "safe" for concurrent use.

Comment: @Affe So `SkipList` would handle the concurrent iteration problem you mentioned in the comment?

Comment: @Geronimo `synchronizedMap` can also handle the concurrent iteration problem. As the documentation states, you need to synchronize on the returned `Map` instance while you iterate over any of its collection views.

Comment: Bear in mind introducing that into a servlet filter introduces a single shared resource every web request is contending for!

Comment: @Geronimo Affe has a great point. This is a textbook use-case for something like Redis or one of the other NoSQL solutions.

Comment: @Affe That is a good point, I will need to see if it that is too drastic, I posted my whole reasoning above in case there was some negative feedback to it like that. Is there a better way to go about this based on my concept above?

Comment: @HankGay Saw your comment after mine, I'm looking them up now, thanks.

Comment: @Geronimo IMO (based on the limited description of your use case in the ? of course), the skiplist is the ideal data structure for you.  (of those built into JDK anyway.)  srry for spamming up comments!  done now

Answer (score 1):

You can make any underlying map synchronized by wrapping it with [java.util.Collections.synchronizedMap(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)

So, you would do:

```
Map m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you get by with using `Collections#synchronizedMap(Map)` and passing it a `LinkedHashMap`? That's the easiest way.

UPDATE: You might also be able to leverage [Guava's `MapMaker`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MapMaker.html) somehow, but I don't think it's 100% on-point.

Answer (score 1):

You can make any map/collection synchronized:

```
Map<...> m = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap());
```

There's `synchronizedSet()`, `synchronizedList()` etc., there's even `synchronizedSortedMap()`.

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Use `HashTable`, which **is the synchronized Map among the Maps**

**2.** You can also use `ConcurrentHashMap`.